# How to retrieve two fields with identical name coming from different tables with ASP and SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, database, asp-classic

First of all, forgive me if this is a weird question, but it clear isn't for me.

I try to do this:

```
    sql="SELECT Alerts.id, Alerts.id_person, Alerts.type, Alerts.date, 
    People.id, People.name, FROM Alerts, People
    WHERE People.name='"& name &"' AND People.id=Alerts.id_person"
    set RS=oADO.Execute(sql)
```

But, as both *Alerts* and *People* have a field named *id*, I have a problem refering to them.
I'm not allowed to do 
`RS.Fields("Alerts.id")` or `RS.Fields("People.id")`, only `RS.Fields("id")`
And that doesn't let me choose wich field I want to use (and actually I'd need to use both of them).

I cannot change the structure of the DDBB (it hasn't been made by me).

Any hint of what I can do? Thank you very much.

I forgot to say that this is going to select many entries, and i'll play with them with a

```
While not RS.EOF
Lorep Ipsum
Wend
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make an alias for a column name using "as" in your select statement:

example: `People.id as PersonID`

```
sql="SELECT Alerts.id, Alerts.id_person, Alerts.type, Alerts.date, 
    People.id as PersonID, People.name, FROM Alerts, People
    WHERE People.name='"& name &"' AND People.id=Alerts.id_person"
```

This allows you to use:

```
RS.Fields("PersonID")
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It's simply what I was looking for. THANK YOU. (I'll accept it in 9 minutes, when it'll be possible)